Android Manifest AD_ID declaration warning in Google Play Console
I have a Flutter app that uses Google Analytics with it, so I added the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission to the main AndroidManifest.xml file. I also declared in Google Play Console that the app is using this permission.
So everything should be fine, right?
However, when I try to submit my build, I get this warning:
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

If I remove advertising declaration, I get this warning:
This release includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission but your declaration on Play Console says your app doesn't use advertising ID.

You must update your advertising ID declaration.

So first, it doesn't recognize the permission, then suddenly it does but only when I remove the declaration from the Console, which one should not do. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this loop?
